# flip flop related question

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, flipflop, logic-gates

Figure 1 and 2 shows a rising-edge triggered JK flip-flop (JK-FF). When CLR = 0, the value of Q after rise is determined by the values ​​of J, K and Q at the rise of the clock pulse CK . However, when CLR = 1, immediately without regard to J, K, CK values Q = 0 and Q - 1. Connect this JK-FF as shown in Fig. 3, and show the outputs Q1 and Q2 when giving each signal as shown in Fig. 4

i really havent learn anything about counters, is this problem related to counter? or only flip flop, can someone give me hint what this problem related to?
thankyou so much!!!!!!!!!!

fig 1
[image: fig 1]

fig 2
[image]

fig 3
[image]

fig 4
[image]

My attempt after someone gave me hint:
[image]

more precise
[image]

is this true? the question want me to draw the diagram(?) or find exact value of q1 and q2? thanks!!

Comment: Clearly a homework problem with no shown attempt at a solution.

Comment: @Trevor_G i was clueless at first, but after someone gave me hint at least i tried to solve it.

Comment: HINT: When J and K are tied together the flip-flop is equal to a standard 'D' flip flop, where 'D' is the same as J&&K. Study the 74HC74 or 74LS74 'D' flip flops. Study counters like the 74HC163 and others that use many flip-flops to count. Study and learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counters are made from flip-flops. This is also a counter which produces different counts on each clock cycle, based on the inputs X and Y. This is an asynchronous counter because the first flip-flop is clocked by CK and the second flip-flop is clocked by the Q' of the first flip-flop. Both the flip-flops are rising edge triggered. CLR is an active-low asynchronous signal to clear the Q outputs of flip-flops anytime. You have the input waveforms for X and Y. You have the truth table for JK flip-flop as well. All left is to look at the waveform and the truth table, and find the outputs for each rising clock edge on both flip-flops.

Comment: thanks for the hint! i posted my work, can you check it if my attempt is right or not(?) what i got from the timing diagram is the input of x is always high(1) so j and k will always 1 and will always toggle, but according to the diagram is the initial value for q1 and q2 is 0? and i made the q1,q2 output diagram from the start of the clock when the first rising edge of the clock Y right(?)

Comment: Last figure. If j= k = 1..that's how's waveforms go. So yea correct.

Comment: thankyou so much!!!!!!!

Comment: Yea you can see the count going like 00-01-10-11-00 ....